# Unable to select radio button in MaterializeCSS when there are two IDs

Tags: materialize

I have a input radio button with two different id tied to it

```
<input type="radio" checked id="setProxyBtn" data-profileid="direct"/>
<label for="setProxyBtn">direct</label>
<input type="radio" checked id="setProxyBtn" data-profileid="fixed_servers"/>
<label for="setProxyBtn">fixed_servers</label>
```

I tried this approach...

```
<input type="radio" checked id="setProxyBtn" data-profileid="direct"/>
<label for="direct">direct</label>
<input type="radio" id="setProxyBtn" data-profileid="fixed_servers"/>
<label for="fixed_servers">fixed_servers</label>
```

tried this approach too...

```
<input type="radio" checked id="setProxyBtn" data-profileid="direct"/>
<label for="setProxyBtn direct">direct</label>
<input type="radio" id="setProxyBtn" data-profileid="fixed_servers"/>
<label for="setProxyBtn fixed_servers">fixed_servers</label>
```

None of them seem to allow the user to select the second radio button, any guidance on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I think its because the id for both the html elements is the same? `id="setProxyBtn"`

Comment: right, I am using the id to call a single function that iterates through data-profileid inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, as @light pointed out I was using the same id for both. So I made the id's dynamic and used jquery to listen to events on elements that are not in the DOM yet.

base.html code changed to ...

```
<input type="radio" checked id="setProxyBtn_direct" data-profileid="direct"/>
<label for="setProxyBtn">direct</label>
<input type="radio" checked id="setProxyBtn_'+profileId+'" data-profileid="'+profileId+'"/>
<label for="setProxyBtn_'+profileId+'">'+profile_desc+'</label>
```

base.js code changed to ...

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^=setProxyBtn_]', function(){
```

Comment: you can also specify a class name and use that as well. At least thats what I would have done: `document.getElementsByClassName('proxybtn').forEach(btn=>btn.addEventListener('click', function(){}))`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `name` attribute?

```
<input type="radio" name="radioButtonGroup" checked id="setProxyBtn" data-profileid="direct"/>
<label for="direct">direct</label>
<input type="radio" name="radioButtonGroup" id="setProxyBtn" data-profileid="fixed_servers"/>
<label for="fixed_servers">fixed_servers</label>
```

Source:https://materializecss.com/radio-buttons.html